# Travel from Mexico to Canada and United States

Tags: usa, air-travel, canada, mexico

My Mexican son in law is coming to visit Vancouver from Cancan for Christmas. He would like to drive to Seattle and see a football game during his visit.

Would he be able to drive to Seattle and return to Vancouver by car, crossing the land border in Blaine Washington?

Comment: where is Cancan?

Answer (score 6):

Presuming your son in law is a Mexico citizen, then he will require a visa in order to enter the US, regardless of whether he is entering by land or by air.

The fact that he is currently in Canada does not change that - it is his citizenship that matters.